# Error de gradle

Tags: android, gradle, jetpack-compose

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

- What went wrong:or --debug option to get more log output.
  Unable to start the daemon process.hts.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.For more details on the daemon, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html in the Gradle documentation.
  Process command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre-1.8\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=ES -Duser.language=es -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\jorge.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-8.2-bin\bbg7u40eoinfdyxsxr3z4i7ta\gradle-8.2\lib\gradC:\Usercher-8.2.jar -javaagent:C:\Users\jorge.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-8.2-bin\bbg7u40eoinfdyxsxr3z4i7ta\gradle-8.2\lib\agents\gradle-instrumentation-agent-8.2.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 8.2
  Please read the following process output to find out more:

---

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

No sé como solucionar este error.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa si tu jvm es de 32 o 64 bits y aumenta la respuesta a eso a la pregunta. Usualmente ese es el problema, con 32 bits tienes menos espacio de ram a usar

Comment: @javdromero mi version de java es: java version "1.8.0_401"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_401-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.401-b10, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0):

El error se describe aquí:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough
> space for 2097152KB object heap

Es un problems relacionado a memoria, te sugiero ubicar tu achivo `gradle.properties` y editarlo modificando `-Xmx`, que se utiliza para especificar el límite superior del tamaño de la memoria dinámica de Java (Heap size), aumenta la memoría:

```
-Xmx1GB
```